# How to solve: Could not run build action using connection to Gradle distribution issue in eclipse?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

The problem occurred, In eclipse, the project was refreshed by *right-clicked project* > Gradle > Refresh Gradle Project

I have tried different approaches, downloading \gradle-4.3.1 file, and by going window > preferences > local installation directory > c:\gradle-4.3.1

[Gradle Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aft4e.png)

```
    apply plugin: 'java'
    repositories {
     mavenCentral()
    }
    buildscript {
      repositories {
      maven {
        url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
      }
    }
    dependencies {
    classpath "com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:6.1.0"
     }
    }
    apply plugin: "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow"
    task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.XXXX.webservices.samples.Controller'          
    }
    baseName = 'XXXXX'
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
    }
    jar {
     baseName = 'XXXX'
      from('src/main') {
        include 'resources/*.properties'
      }
    manifest {
       attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.netsuite.webservices.samples.Controller'       
     }
    }
    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', includes: ['suitetalk-*0.jar'])
    compile 'axis:axis:1.4'
    runtime 'commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.1'
    runtime 'org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:1.7.6'
    runtime 'org.slf4j:slf4j-nop:1.7.25'

    compileOnly 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1'
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'
    task runApplication(type: JavaExec) {
    description "Builds and executes the sample application"
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main = "com.netsuite.webservices.samples.Controller"
    standardInput = System.in
    }
```